# Host external domain on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, subdomain, web-hosting

I want to register a website and want to host the same on google app engine. I dont want any sub-domain like .appspot.com.

I read a lot about GAE but I think I ended up with confusion.

Suppose the domain is: www.mydomain.com. Can I use google app engine without any sub-domain? And then will I be eligible for GAE free services?

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine no longer supports mapping your app to a naked domain. If your domain registrar supports URL redirects, you can redirect from http://yourdomain.com to your app, which can be served from domains like http://www.yourdomain.com or http://appid.yourdomain.com.

[*SOURCE](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=91080)